# Override implicit parameter in a method called on an object, with the ability to manipulate this object

Tags: scala

> edit: I edited the title to discourage people from advising me
>   to explicitly provide the implicit parameter

I've been struggling with the below example, and wasn't able to find a solution for a while now. I've extracted the scheme of the problem from a bigger project (flink-ml) but it's a scala problem.

### The setup

Basically, I have the following setup for the part I'm dealing with:

```
//design to fit multiple models
trait PredictOperation[Self, InputType, OutputType] {
  def doPrediction(input: InputType): OutputType
}

class Predictor[Model] {
  def predict[InputType, OutputType](
    param1: InputType)(implicit
    predictOperation: PredictOperation[Model, InputType, OutputType])
  : OutputType =
  {
    predictOperation.doPrediction(param1)
  }
}


//a particular model that uses the above design
class SampleModel extends Predictor[SampleModel] {
  //...
}
object SampleModel {
  implicit val samplePredictOperation = new PredictOperation[SampleModel, Int, Double]{
    override def doPrediction(input:Int):Double = 2.0*input
  }
}

//some object using this model
object SomeObjectUsingModelPredict{
  def SomeFunctionUsingModelPredict(m : SampleModel): Unit ={
    println(m.predict(3))
  }
}
```

I use `SomeObjectUsingModelPredict.SomeFunctionUsingModelPredict` in my code:

```
//I want to override the doPrediction function of the model
object MainObject{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
    val m = new SampleModel
    SomeObjectUsingModelPredict.SomeFunctionUsingModelPredict(m)
    //outputs 6.0
  }
}
```

### The goal

I want to override the `doPrediction` function of SampleModel and hand `SomeFunctionUsingModelPredict` an object that behaves according to this overridden behavior (outputs 9.0 for this particular example).

### Attempts

I've tried a few things, none of which work:

```
//method 'predict' overrides nothing
object MainObject{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
    val m = new SampleModel{
      override def predict(param1: Int)(implicit predictOperation: PredictOperation[SampleModel, Int, Double]): Double = 3*param1
    }
    SomeObjectUsingModelPredict.SomeFunctionUsingModelPredict(m)
  }
}

//outputs 6.0
object MainObject{'predict' overrides nothing
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
    implicit val samplePredictOperation = new PredictOperation[SampleModel, Int, Double]{
      override def doPrediction(input:Int):Double = 3.0*input
    }
    val m = new SampleModel
    SomeObjectUsingModelPredict.SomeFunctionUsingModelPredict(m)
  }
}

//outputs 6.0
object MainObject{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
    val m = new SampleModel{
      implicit val samplePredictOperation = new PredictOperation[SampleModel, Int, Double]{
        override def doPrediction(input:Int):Double = 3.0*input
      }
      override def predict[InputType, OutputType](param1: InputType)(implicit predictOperation: PredictOperation[SampleModel, InputType, OutputType]): OutputType = super.predict(param1)(predictOperation)
    }
    SomeObjectUsingModelPredict.SomeFunctionUsingModelPredict(m)
  }
}

//outputs 6.0
object MainObject{
  class ExtSampleModel extends SampleModel {
    override def predict[InputType, OutputType](param1: InputType)(implicit predictOperation: PredictOperation[SampleModel, InputType, OutputType]): OutputType = super.predict(param1)(predictOperation)
  }
  object ExtSampleModel{
    implicit val samplePredictOperation = new PredictOperation[SampleModel, Int, Double]{
      override def doPrediction(input:Int):Double = 3.0*input
    }
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
    val m = new ExtSampleModel
    SomeObjectUsingModelPredict.SomeFunctionUsingModelPredict(m)
  }
}
```

### Question

Is it possible to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Ideas for refactoring are always welcome, but **I'm primarily curious about this for the sake of the problem itself**.

I can't really touch much of this design, at the moment I've worked around the problem by refactoring `SomeObjectUsingModelPredict`.

Comment: Consider that all `implicit` parameter does is *if the argument is not provided explicitly look for a matching implicit*. So just provide one.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not the one calling the method that takes the implicit parameter, I'm just providing an object that the method gets called on. Still, attempts 2 and 3 try to set the implicit parameter explicitly, to no avail.

Comment: The reference that gets passed as an implicit argument is statically determined at the point that the `predict` method gets called. So if you have no control over the callsite you cannot override which object gets passed.

Comment: @Jasper-M: even if I can override the original predict call and call it as super.predict? Note: so far I've not been able to provide the implicit parameter explicitly in the overridden `predict` because of type templates.

Comment: I guess you can override the original predict call and implement that as `super.predict(???)(yourCustomPredictOperation)`. But then you simply throw away the `PredictOperation` that gets passed to your `predict` method and replace it with your own. If it's really necessary I guess you can use such a hack internally, but you don't want to expose that to other people. If you have to bypass the design with a hack, there's usually something wrong.

Comment: @Jasper-M In the project I'm doing this for testing, so a hack is ok. Also, unrelated to the project I'm curious if it's possible. However, I've not been able to do what you described, since I'm not able to call `super.predict` with concrete types, as it's templated with `InputType` and `OutputType` instead of `Int` and `Double`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a dirty hack you can do it like this. First you have to bypass the implicit parameter by throwing away the `PredictOperation` that your `predict` method receives and replacing it with your own. And then you have to bypass the type system with some casts.

```
object MainObject{
  class ExtSampleModel extends SampleModel {
    private val samplePredictOperation = new PredictOperation[SampleModel, Int, Double]{
      override def doPrediction(input:Int):Double = 3.0*input
    }

    override def predict[InputType, OutputType](param1: InputType)(implicit predictOperation: PredictOperation[SampleModel, InputType, OutputType]): OutputType = 
      super.predict(param1.asInstanceOf[Int])(samplePredictOperation).asInstanceOf[OutputType]
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
    val m = new ExtSampleModel
    SomeObjectUsingModelPredict.SomeFunctionUsingModelPredict(m)
  }
}
```